# Cygwin64 Won't Display My Exectuable for C++

Tags: c++, cygwin

So I'm taking a computer science minor and I need to redownload cygwin64 onto my new laptop I'm getting.  I'm following this guide to install cygwin64:  https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Cygwin_HowTo.html
I am using cygwin to compile .cpp files and running the executable to display on the terminal.  For whatever reason, I can compile but when I run the .exe that is made, it doesn't output anything from my code.  Keep in mind I use cygwin for my old laptop and it works there.  I don't remember the steps I did to download it and get it working properly.  Here is an example code I compiled and then ran on my old laptop and now on my new laptop along with the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
using namespace std;

int count_nodes(forward_list<int> lst, forward_list<int>::iterator it, int cnt = 0){
    if(it == lst.end()){
        return cnt;
    } else {
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        it++;
        return count_nodes(lst,it,cnt);
    }
}
int main() {
    forward_list<int> first;
    forward_list<int> second;
    forward_list<int> third;
    first.assign({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    second.assign({1,2,3,4,5});
    third.assign({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15});
    cout << "First Count: " << count_nodes(first,first.begin()) << endl;
    cout << "Second Count: " << count_nodes(second,second.begin()) << endl;
    cout << "Third Count: " << count_nodes(third,third.begin()) << endl;
}
```

[Old Laptop Cygwin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OvGm.png)

[New Laptop Cygwin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIbOS.png)

So my question is what did I do wrong? What didn't I download?

Comment: Try adding a .exe at the end? The new laptop might be not recognizing it.

Comment: Be interesting to see what happens when you run the program under gdb.

Comment: Hey, try this experiment:  Highlight the command line text you want to copy, the press <ctrl><Insert>.  Edit your question and then paste the text in your question.  Did it work?
I have often highlighted Cygwin command prompts and pasted into other documents.  Interestingly, text is more scalable than images and takes up less space.

Comment: It looks like you are not running a Cygwin build of `g++` and that you have some MinGW installation on your path.  What does `echo $PATH` show, and what does `which g++` show?  Re-run the Cygwin installer and make sure the build-essential package is selected.